# How to write a distribution of piecewise functions in R?

Tags: r

How to write a distribution of piecewise functions in R? For example, if a random variable `X` is a `N(0,1)` if `p=1` and `X~N(0,2)` when `p=0`. I try the following code:

```
   if(p==1)(X=rnorm(1,0,2))?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`:

```
X <- function(size){
  ifelse(sample(0:1,size,replace = TRUE),rnorm(size,0,1),rnorm(size,0,2))
}
```

50% of the time (on average), `X` will sample from a `N(0,1)` variable and the other 50% of the time it will sample from `N(0,2)`.

How it works can be seen more clearly if you change the definition of `X` so that the means of the two variables sampled from are different:

```
X <- function(size){
  ifelse(sample(0:1,size,replace = TRUE),rnorm(size,0,1),rnorm(size,4,1))
}
```

Then `hist(X(10000))` yields:
[image]

Comment: Can I just write `ifelse(p==1, rnorm(1, 0,1), rnorm(1,0,2))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

#define the function pieces 
g =function(x) rnorm(1,0,2)
h =function(x) rnorm(1,0,1) 

#define the input 
p = c(1,0,1,1,0) 
#longer input
#p = sample(c(0,1),2000,replace = T)

piecewise_function= function(p) {
  
  case_when( p==1 ~ g() ,      # a condition a tilde and a function
             p==0 ~ h() ,
             T ~ NA)        #what to do if neither condition is met.
  }

piecewise_function(p)
```

Comment: Can I just write `ifelse(p==1, rnorm(1, 0,1), rnorm(1,0,2))`?

Comment: yes, my intention here is to write something that could stand up to additional complexities later. have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these where n is the number of sample size:

```
rnorm(n, 0, 1 * (p == 1) + 2 * (p == 0))

rnorm(n, 0, ifelse(p == 1, 1, 2))

rnorm(n, 0, 1 + !p)
```

Comment: Can I just write `ifelse(p==1, rnorm(1, 0,1), rnorm(1,0,2))`?

Comment: But how about `N(mu1, sigma1)` and `N(mu2, sigma2)`?

Comment: The `ifelse` in the comment is undesirable because it will run both rnorm's and then throw away one of them but if p is a scalar then you can use `result <- if (p ==1) rnorm(mu1, sigma1) else rnorm(mu2, signma2)` or `if (p == 1) { mu <- mu1; sigma <- sigma1 } else { mu <- mu2; sigma <- sigma2 }; rnorm(n, mu, sigma)`